# Not able to install VLC 17.04

Tags: vlc

I used

```
% sudo apt-get update 
% sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
```

I am getting

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vlc
E: Unable to locate package browser-plugin-vlc
```

Comment: 17.04 is no longer supported, which includes software downloads. You should upgrade to 17.10 to get that and things like security updates. Follow @FlorianDiesch's link above to upgrade to 17.10. Then installing VLC should work.

Comment: Zesty archive was taken off-line (it reached EOL 13-Jan-2018); you'll need to change it to use `old-releases.ubuntu.com` (in place of archive.ubuntu.com).  If you look [with a browser] at archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu (or whatever site you're using in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`) there is no 'zesty' directory anymore; it's been moved to old-releases already.  Zesty was NOT patched for Meltdown, any part of Spectre (next patches eta 22-Jan) etc so upgrading to 17.10 is advisible, or using a LTS (eg. 16.04LTS) if you don't like upgrading often.

Answer (score 0):

Open a Terminal an type the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Vlc was not found because it's only available in the [universe repository.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/vlc)

Comment: Tried that already, I am getting same error,  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vlc

Comment: Universe is enabled by default in Ubuntu.